# Click all buttons with id starting with 'ok_' using javascript

Tags: javascript

I have some buttons with ids: `ok_1`, `ok_2`, `ok_3`...

How to click all buttons with ids that start with `ok_` using javascript?

Comment: You should add [minimal reproducible code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), so that people can understand your problem clearly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use an [attribute selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) that checks for prefix (^=):

```js
document.querySelectorAll('[id^="ok_"]').forEach(btn => btn.click());
```